# Rendering django form in view

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to django, and I want to extend the user model with another class. However, I am not sure how to get the form to work properly with the class Device. I would like temperature, and battery to show up in the form. Thank you very much in advance :)

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    temperature = models.IntegerField()
    battery = models.IntegerField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    deviceNb= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, null=True) 

User.profile = property(lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('deviceNb', 'device', )
```

views.py

```
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':            
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)


        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            #to go back to check that the info has changed
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')

    else: # when this is a get request
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```

Comment: inline formsets are the answer.  from the documents:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Note it should be `if form.is_valid()`. If you forget the parentheses and write `if form.is_valid`, then `form.is_valid` will *always* evaluate to True.

Comment: thanks for the tip ! Will make the change indeed . :)

Comment: @ivan7707 inline formsets are useful if you want to edit many devices related to one profile (or many profiles related to one device), but are not so useful in this case where you want to edit one profile and one device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `device` field from the `UserProfile` form - you want to edit the existing device, not change it to a different device.

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('deviceNb',)
```

Then create a device form.

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('temperature', 'battery',)
```

Then update your view to handle two forms. For example, you need to instantiate both forms, check that both are valid, save both forms if they are valid, and so on. In case the `device` does not exist, you can save the profile form with `commit=False` to get the `profile`, set the device, then finally save the profile.

```
def user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    device = profile.device
    if request.method == 'POST':            
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        device_form = DeviceForm(request.POST, instance=device)

        if form.is_valid() and device_form.is_valid():
            device = device_form.save()
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.device = device
            profile.save()
            #to go back to check that the info has changed
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')

    else: # when this is a get request
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
        device_form = DeviceForm(instance=device)

    args = {}
    # Delete the following line - you don't need it now that you use render
    # args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    args['device_form'] = device_form

    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)
```

Finally, in your template, include both forms in the same `<form>` tag.

```
<form method='post'>
   {{ form }}
   {{ device_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```